# No puedo crear la clase

Tags: javascript, class, constructor

Estoy teniendo un problema para generar la siguiente clase:

```
   **function crearClaseProfesor() {
  Crear una clase para construir objeto de tipo Profesor.
  el constructor debe recibir:
  nombre (string) , edad (integer) , cursos (array de strings) , certificados (array de objetos)
  Esta funcion debe retonar la clase Profesor.
  class Profesor {
    constructor() {
}**
```

lo hice de la siguiente manera, sin embargo no me pasa. Me pueden ayudar, debe ser porque no contiene los parametros el constructor pero no encontre nada de info que me ayude.Gracias.

```
**function crearClaseProfesor() {
  class Profesor {
    constructor() {
this.string= string;
this.edad= edad;
this.cursos= cursos;
this.certificados=certificados
}**
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que quiere decir no me pasa??? y si, ese constructor no recibe parametros.. y obviamente un constructor no devuelve nada.. y tu clase debe ir afuera de la funcion que tenes que crear.. y varias cosas mas...

Comment: Cual es el sentido de la función `crearClaseProfesor`?

Answer (score 2):

No funciona del modo en que intentas plantearlo.

Debes pensar la clase como un molde, el cual usarás cada vez que necesites crear un objeto del tipo `Profesor`. Por tanto, la clase debe ser definida **fuera de la función**.

Luego, dentro de la función instancias la clase, pasándole los datos que tendrá la misma.

Veamos un ejemplo:

```js
/*
  Clase Profesor
  Este código debe existir UNA SOLA VEZ
  en tu aplicación, así como está,
  no dentro de funciones
*/

class Profesor {
  constructor(nombre, edad, cursos, certificados) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.cursos = cursos;
    this.certificados = certificados;
  }

  getNombre() {
    return this.nombre;
  }

  getEdad() {
    return this.edad;
  }

  getCursos() {
    let str = "";
    this.cursos.forEach(item => str += `\t${item}\n`);
    return str;
  }

  getCertificados() {
    let str = "";
    this.certificados.forEach(item => str += `\tid: ${item.id}\ttitulo: ${item.titulo}\n`);
    return str;
  }

  toString() {
    console.log(`nombre: ${this.getNombre()}\nedad:${this.getEdad()}\ncursos:\n${this.getCursos()}\ncertificados:\n${this.getCertificados()}`);
  }

}

/*
  Función del EJERCICIO
  destinada a crear y devolver una instancia
  de la clase Profesor
  Cabe decir que una función como esta
  no tiene ningún sentido en aplicaciones reales
  porque esto ya lo hace el constructor de la clase
  (ver el segundo fragmento de código,
   donde se prescinde de esta función)
*/

function crearClaseProfesor(nombre, edad, cursos, certificados) {
  return new Profesor(nombre, edad, cursos, certificados);
}

/*
  Probamos la función
  y el método toString()
  de la clase Profesor
*/
let unProfesor = crearClaseProfesor('Pedro', 50, [1, 5, 7, 8], [{
    id: 7,
    titulo: 'Profe del mes'
  }, {
    id: 8,
    titulo: 'Profe del nivel'
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    titulo: 'Profe del año'
  }
]);
unProfesor.toString();
```

PEROOOO, realmente, el que te pidan crear una función que cree una instancia de una clase puede llevar a confusión, porque es algo inútil. Y es que `crearProfesor()` recibe en parámetro los mismos datos que recibe el constructor de la clase. ¿Para qué marear tanto los datos pasándolos de un lado para otro? Puedes hacer algo así simplemente:

```js
/*
  Clase Profesor
  Este código debe existir UNA SOLA VEZ
  en tu aplicación, así como está,
  no dentro de funciones
*/

class Profesor {
  constructor(nombre, edad, cursos, certificados) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.cursos = cursos;
    this.certificados = certificados;
  }

  getNombre() {
    return this.nombre;
  }

  getEdad() {
    return this.edad;
  }

  getCursos() {
    let str = "";
    this.cursos.forEach(item => str += `\t${item}\n`);
    return str;
  }

  getCertificados() {
    let str = "";
    this.certificados.forEach(item => str += `\tid: ${item.id}\ttitulo: ${item.titulo}\n`);
    return str;
  }

  toString() {
    console.log(`nombre: ${this.getNombre()}\nedad:${this.getEdad()}\ncursos:\n${this.getCursos()}\ncertificados:\n${this.getCertificados()}`);
  }

}


let unProfesor = new Profesor('Pedro', 50, [1, 5, 7, 8], [{
    id: 7,
    titulo: 'Profe del mes'
  }, {
    id: 8,
    titulo: 'Profe del nivel'
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    titulo: 'Profe del año'
  }
]);

unProfesor.toString();
```

Como ves, funciona igual. Pero no voy a juzgar el que te hayan pedido algo que ya lo hace el constructor de la clase.

Answer (score 1):

El planteo de tu pregunta es bastante confuso... espero haberlo entendido bien.

Empecemos con la estructura de la clase:

```
class Profesor {

}
```

Ahora bien, te piden que tenga un constructor.

```
constructor() {
```

Seguro notas la similitud con una función, el constructor es una función, con una tarea especifica.

Ahora bien, te piden que el constructor reciba parámetros (parámetros = datos que necesita la función para trabajar sobre o con ellos).

```
constructor( nombre, edad, cursos, certificados ) {
```

Después de crear el constructor, debemos inicializar los campos.

```
this.nombre = nombre;
this.edad = edad;
this.cursos = cursos;
this.certificados = certificados;
```

Si usamos la palabra reservada **this** hacemos referencia a las varibles de la clase, y si no, a los parámetros recibidos.

En resumen:

```
class Profesor {
    constructor( nombre, edad, cursos, certificados ) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.cursos = cursos;
    this.certificados = certificados;
}
```

Ahora vamos con la función que crea ***Profesores***.

```
function crearProfesor( nombre, edad, cursos, certificados ) {
       // declaramos el profe y le pasamos al constructor los parámetros
    Profesor nuevoProfe = new Profesor( nombre, edad, cursos, certificados );
       // retornamos el profe creado
    return nuevoProfe;
}
```